# What fraction of the training set should I use?

Tags: cross-validation, random-forest, scikit-learn, model-evaluation

I tried to fit `RandomForestClassifier` with `n_estimators=500` to the training dataset which has 600,000 instances and it's taking too long. I'm also planning to use `RandomizedSearchCV`. What fraction of the training data should I use for `RandomizedSearchCV` fitting to be finished in reasonable amount of time?

Comment: Is the result good by using RandomForestClassifier? I think you need to first choose the model that achieves high accuracy, then think about tuning parameters.

Comment: @YiYang The `roc_auc_score` is about 0.6 for the random forest and even lower for logistin regression. What would be a better model to try?

Comment: have you tried svm?

Comment: @YiYang I have to predict probabilities of two classes, and svm classifier in sklearn doesn't have `predict_proba` method so I guess it's not an option.

Answer (score 2):

No one can really answer that question without knowing the data. But since you have a lot of data, you should partition your data into 3 parts, use the first partition to find the best model parameters (tuning), use the second partition to train your model, and the third to test it. This should cut down the time by a third. If it's still too much consider taking a random subsample out of each partition.

Comment: Thank you! And which scikit-learn or other python library method takes random subsamples?

Comment: Can't help you with Python, but there should be a simple way of doing this, something like `sample()` rows of your data.

Answer (score 1):

Although I completely agree with user2974951, I might want to throw in some ideas to speed up the process without the need to code to much extra:

1) 500 trees is a whole lot. Start with smaller values like 50 and then increase it until you see that the classifier performance plateaus.

2) After taking care of the number of trees, this leaves the only important parameter to be the number of features used per tree in the forest (there are actually more as in spark for example, but those are not found in all implementations so i pass on them here). Since you are doing classification, start with `sqrt(m)` if `m` is the number of features. From there increase in little steps if you need higher performance or decrease if you are overfitting to much.

3) adding to user2974951's answer: i generally start with a 70%/30% split. The 70% you use for cross validation and in order to determine the hyperparameters talked above and 30% for evaluation. That reduces the number of training instances.

4) If the number of examples is very high given the number of features (see the [one-in-ten rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_in_ten_rule) ), you could also try to just do a train-validation split, which basically is a "1-fold-cross-validation" with  split-percentages which you specify. I had several occasions where all n folds of a cv returned nearly the same model performances. Take this hint with caution tho, since this is not always the case.

Comment: Thanks, it was very helpful! So I can choose the hyperparameters like number of trees and number of features used per tree manually without running RandomizedSearchCV or GridSearchCV in this case?

Comment: This should be possible yes. All random forest implementations I know (some in R and the one in spark)  provide parameters to set this manually. I understand that it is tedious to manually look after each tested iteration if your model performance plateaus e.g. but actually I bet that you will not use so many iterations til you got the final number of trees or number of features to use.